# Alternative jquery rating plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, radio-button, rating

The title is not very illustrating, but I'll try to explain.

I'm looking for a jquery rating plugin which behaves like a standard star rating, but supports different images and colors depending on the selected value

For example, on the scale of 1-10:

- 1-3 when hovered or selected all images/colors are red
- 4-7 when hovered or selected all images/colors are yellow
- 8-10 when hovered or selected all images/colors are green

I found [this](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/) and [this](http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/#main-menu=1&demo-tabs=8). but they don't quite do what I'm looking for.

So if anyone knows if there is something out there will save me a lot of time for creating a new plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make your own? I've already built a little demo to show that it's possible: http://jsfiddle.net/s2zPW/18/.

The code isn't that hard either:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="rating"></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.fn.reverse = function() {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};

// create two new functions: prevALL and nextALL. they're very similar, hence this style.
$.each(['prev', 'next'], function(unusedIndex, name) {
    $.fn[name + 'ALL'] = function(matchExpr) {
        // get all the elements in the body, including the body.
        var $all = $('body').find('*').andSelf();

        // slice the $all object according to which way we're looking
        $all = (name == 'prev') ? $all.slice(0, $all.index(this)).reverse() : $all.slice($all.index(this) + 1);
        // filter the matches if specified
        if (matchExpr) $all = $all.filter(matchExpr);
        return $all;
    };
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('.rating').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
}

$('.rating li').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).index() < 2) {
        $(this).prevALL('li').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 160, 160)');
    } else if ($(this).index() < 4) {
        $(this).prevALL('li').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 200, 200)');
    } else if ($(this).index() < 7) {
        $(this).prevALL('li').css('background-color', 'rgb(235, 220, 200)');
    } else if ($(this).index() < 10) {
        $(this).prevALL('li').css('background-color', 'rgb(200, 255, 200)');
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().children().css('background-color', 'rgb(200, 200, 200)');
});
```

Comment: wow, i wasn't expecting this much help, thanks a lot!... ill build on your example, there are still some things that need to be done to make it behave like a form element

Comment: Bugger, beat me to it. Here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/wea3b/ -- quite a bit smaller ;-)

Comment: Yours is a lot cleaner, might I add. I'd +1 it if it were an answer.